# How to match external_subcommand and other normal commands at the same time?

Tags: rust

So I have this StructOpt:

```
#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
pub enum Command{
    #[structopt(name = "init")]
    Init,
    #[structopt(name= "continue")]
    Continue,
    // Pass through unknown commands to the Clap parser
    #[structopt(external_subcommand)]
    Options(Vec<String>),
}
```

My question is how am I going to match the possible external_subcommand and others at the same time as Options(Vec<String>) can be None?

My current solution is as below but does not seem right. (Some middle process is omitted)

```
match options{
    Command::Options(opts) => {}
    Command::Init => {do_the_init();}
    Command::Continue => {do_continue();}     
}
```

The `Vec<String>` is passed to another struct as below:

```
pub struct RootOptions {
    pub output_path: String,
    pub verbosity_level: LevelFilter,
    pub run_docgen: bool,
    ...
}
```

And the function `create_from_args` pass the args into the cli defined inside.

```
impl RootOptions {
  pub fn create_from_args(args: &[String]) -> anyhow::Result<Options> {
    let cli = App::new("cli")
        .version("0.1.0")
        .about("The Command Cli")
        .author("Team")
        .arg(...
    // The detail of args are omitted here

    let matches = cli.get_matches_from(args);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Given the different command input options, link to different actions. For example, if the command is Init, that will lead to a `do_the_init() function`. My question here is I don't know how to match `external_subcommand`(which is `Options(Vec<String>)` in the given example) with other commands.

Comment: BTW structopt is deprecated and it's recommended to use clap's derive feature instead.

Comment: Your clarification doesn't help much. Please provide more code context and explain exactly what you are trying to do. You have a comment saying "Pass through unknown commands to the Clap parser". Do you have a second Clap parser instance that you want to pass the `Vec<String>` to? Why do you even have external subcommands, like why can't you just handle them in your main `Command` enum as well?

Comment: @PitaJ Yes I do have a second Clap parser, and i need external subcommands as I need to pass the commands defined by this second parser to the second Clap parser.

Comment: Is the other parser also derived, or is it created with `clap::Command`? Please share more code. You still haven't explained why you must use `external_subcommand` instead of just handling everything with a single instance.